# Sqlite store string value in numeric or real datatypes

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite as backend database for my application and storing float value in **'real'** datatype column but it also store string value.
I know data can be check at front end side but i want to know why sqlite not checking data on inserting record.

please check Au column it store both value.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite uses dynamic typing i.e. the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. It does not enforce data type constraints. You can store data of any type in any column. Read more about this [here](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3) and Datatypes in SQLite [here](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Excerpt from [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible with the more common static type systems of other database engines in the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.

**In your case,** SQLite tried to convert the value you passed i.e. `asasassas` into double / floating value, but since it failed to do that, it has inserted the value as a `string`. This feature of SQLite is called [type affinity](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).